# How to create a regex to match everything inside and including <div>...</div>?

Tags: regex, html-parsing

This is the sample text that I'm working with. I'm using Coda to do a find and replace...

```
<td width="20%"><div > Item #</div></td>
<td width="20%"><div > Pole Tip</div></td>
<td width="20%"><div > Length</div></td>
<td width="20%"><div > Test Weight (lbs.)</div></td>
<td width="20%"><div > Price</div></td>
```

I want to get rid of the div tags that markup the text inside the td.

Ex...I want to change this:

```
<td width="20%"><div > Item #</div></td>
```

to this:

```
<td width="20%">Item #</td>
```

---

So far I have this as a regex:

```
<div >[\s\w\(\)#]*</div>
```

However this matches all of the above in my sample text EXCEPT:

```
<td width="20%"><div > Test Weight (lbs.)</div></td>
```

In my regex, I even tried to add the ( and )...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: While regexes might work for this particular code, regexes are a fragile solution to parsing HTML code.  http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html explains why.  The safer solution is to use a proper HTML parser.  What language are you using?

Comment: @AndyLester : I inherited some HTML that I'm trying to clean up. I'm using Coda as my editor and I want to do a global search and replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you missed the `.` This works just fine

```
<div >[\s\w\(\)#.]*</div>
```

Comment: So I was missing the '.' for the 'period'? Doh! How come I don't have to escape the '.'?

Comment: You don't need to escape it if it is in a character class.

Comment: Without requiring the TD wrapper in the regex, you'll also be removing div tags all over your page. Also, what if there is a % symbol?  Or any other symbol other than a pound?  That's an odd limiting character class.  If the answer to that is that you're only replacing that exact text in your example, then don't even use regex, just use string literal replacement.  This regex is very flimsy.

Answer (score 1):

In Reply to Andy, I agree that Data Parsing of Well-Formed Markup should be kept to DOM Navigational tools.  XML for sure, or HTML>XML Converters are good.  I don't know what Miles is working with, but I frequently work with HTML that is so malformed that it can't be parsed by Markup parsers.

In some of my Regex tutorials on Document Parsing, I discuss the Regex Trim pattern, which is simply Zero or More Whitespace {\s*}.  Though you might shy away from it because it adds a tiny bit of length to the Regex Pattern, there is virtually zero efficiency loss.  That being said...

```
(<td[^>]*>)\s*<div[^>]*>\s*((?:[^<]*(?(?!</div>\s*</td>)<))*)\s*</div>\s*(</td>)
```

Replace this with $1$2$3 and you win, as well as get back a clean result.  Of course, you can replace or remove as many Trims (\s*) as you like, just a personal preference if I am parsing Documents or Malformed Markup.